# "import as" leads to unresolved import error, "from .. import" does not

Tags: pydev

I'm trying to write some plugins for the irc bot supybot with eclipse/pydev. Pydev gives me errors about unresolved imports on supybot-modules/packages (e. g. import supybot.utils as utils), but works ok on e. g. "from supybot.commands import *". So I guess I set up dydev correctly, as it finds the wanted modules. The problem must be in pydev/eclipse, as the bot works correct and in eric5 I get also no errors about that.

Removing the interpreter and setting it up didn't help. Any other ideas on how to fix this? System: Arch Linux, Eclipse Juno, PyDev 2.7.1, wanted (and set up) python interpreter is 2.7, supybot is installed in site-packages for Python 2.7.

Edit: Just noticed: PyDev doesn't mark the "from ... import *" as error, but if I use functions imported from there I get an error on that function.

Code sample:

```
[...]
import supybot.utils as utils
from supybot.commands import *
[...]
wunsch = wrap(wunsch, ['text', 'now'])
[...]
```

Error on the first line: Unresolved import: utils
Second line gets no error nor warning
Error on 3rd line: Undefined variable: wrap
    But 'wrap' is a function declared in supybot.commands

Comment: Please include some code samples and copy/paste the actual errors you're receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Run `import supybot; print supybot.__path__` to get the path to the supybot package. PyDev may be importing the wrong one (for example if you use a folder called `supybot` in your workspace).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I created a new file inside that eclipse workspace and only added 

`import supybot;  
print supybot;  
import supybot.utils as utils;  
print utils.__path__`

Both import statements get marked as unresolved (red marker in left and right sidebars). But if I execute it everything works as expected, the pathes are correct: 

`['/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supybot']  
['/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supybot/utils']  
`

Comment: According to your initial most, the first import is resolved, so it should have a `__path__`.

Comment: It prints the correct paths, but marks the import as unresolved in the edittor.